# jsp display:table how to display child rows

Tags: jsp, row, displaytag

I have a jsp and I use display:tag. I want to display child rows when I click in a row. I look for a tutorial but I don't find it.

This is my jsp:

```
<display:table id="ev" name="vcomposiciones" class="display" sort="list" defaultsort="3" defaultorder="ascending" export="true" style="width:90%" requestURI="/copernico/SrvRenfeDatawarehouse" varTotals="totales">
                <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="Composiciones.xls"/>
                <display:column property="fecha" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" title="Fecha" />
                <display:column property="tren" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" title="Tren" />
                <display:column property="numVagon" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" title="Vagón nº" />
                <display:column property="nombreOrigen" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" title="Origen" />            
                <display:column property="nombreDestino" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" title="Destino" />
                <display:column property="codMercancia" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" title="Mercancía" />
                <display:column property="longitud" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" title="Long." format="{0,number,0.00}" total="true"/>    
                <display:column property="ejes" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" title="Ejes" total="true"/>
                <display:column property="tara" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" title="Tara" format="{0,number,0.00}" total="true"/>
                <display:column property="carga" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" title="Carga" format="{0,number,0.00}" total="true"/>   
                <display:column property="regimen" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" title="Régimen" />    
                <display:column property="uti" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" title="C47" />    
                <display:column property="ate" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" title="A.T.E." />
                <display:column property="numeroExpedicion" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" title="Exp." />

                 <display:footer>
                    <tr class="footer">
                      <td align="right" colspan="5"><h2>TOTAL&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></td>
                      <td align="center"><b>Vagones</b></br><c:out value="${vcomposicionSize}" /></td>
                      <td align="center"><b>Long.</b></br><fmt:formatNumber type = "number" pattern="0.00" value="${totales.column7}" /></td>
                      <td align="center"><b>Ejes</b></br><fmt:formatNumber type = "number" pattern="0" value="${totales.column8}" /></td>
                      <td align="center"><b>Tara</b></br><fmt:formatNumber type = "number" pattern="0.00" value="${totales.column9}" /></td>
                      <td align="center"><b>Carga</b></br><fmt:formatNumber type = "number" pattern="0.00" value="${totales.column10}" /></td>
                    <tr>
                 </display:footer>
            </display:table>
```

How can I find information about display:table? How can I do child rows?

Comment: Whats do you mean by child row?

Comment: A expandable table(tree)

Comment: http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.1/example-nestedtables.jsp , like this ?

Comment: Yes, I need click in the row and expand the other ones